# Segmentation fault: Trying to write array of strings in shared memory c

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory-management, segmentation-fault

im trying to implement a basic program which writes an array of strings in shared memory and then it reads it from there. I am constantly taking a segmentation fault. I cant really tell what is wrong ( i have really messed it up ) because i am using shared memory for first time. Any help would be appreciated , thanks!

code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int shmid;
    int i = 0;
    key_t key = 123;
    char (*array)[100][50];

    shmid = shmget(key, 100 * 50, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    array = (char *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);

    // array = malloc(sizeof(int)*count);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        strcpy(array[i], "arrayvalues");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s---\n", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\nWritting to memory succesful[+]\n");

    shmid = shmget(key, 1024, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    array = (char *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s---\n", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\nRead to memory succesful[+]\n");

    shmdt((void *)array);
    // shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** it only saves the array[0] value in shared memory.

Comment: The irony that your name is segfault.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I am really bad in memory management! :)

Comment: Start by checking *shmget* and  *shmat* return values for errors (read the man pages for details). Are the return values ok? (In general, it's pointless to debug bugs on code which lacks basic error checking.)

Comment: @hyde i've tried but i get segmentation fault  on shmget so i cant really check what it returns..

Comment: the posted code fails to cleanly compile!  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. I.E. 10, 123, 50. 100, 1024, .  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the posted code creates two shared memory areas, assigns both pointers to the same variable without out destroying the first shared memory before generating the second shared memory, fails to check for errors, stomps all over the shared memory, writing the same literal starting as successive locations in the shared memory.

Comment: you should use the function: `ftok()` to make the key, not just toss some value at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the segmentation fault is not related to using shared memory.
Actually what you are declaring here (*array)[100][50] is a pointer to a 2D array. But while accessing the same you are treating it as a normal 2D array variable.
Thus, if you access it like (*array)[i] then there is no memory violation.

*array points to the 2D array while array is just the location of the pointer to the array.
You can try populating the array like (*array)[i] and then try to print array[i] in a loop. The 1st element i.e array[0] will be valid as the index 0 will mean nothing but printing *array.
But from index 1 onwards it will try to access locations *(array+1) which may not be valid locations. This causes the segmentation fault. 
But (*array)[i] means accessing location (*array) + 1  which is valid, as arrays are allocated in contagious memory locations

Comment: Welcome! Updated answer about saving array[0] value